# How to use a custom Style Sheet in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, hyperlink

I want to make links on my WordPress page white. For that I tried to include the css-code into the link like this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" style="a:link{ color: white; }">Google</a>
```

This did not work. I Can´t see a style editing or style inserting option on my wp_admin.
How can I get my stylesheet in?

Comment: I think you need to create custom stylesheet for you needs..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a problem with the style syntax, please update the code:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" style="color: white;">Google</a>
```

That will fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To edityour style sheet you need to go to the Appearance TAB at the left side of your WP_admin. in the TAb Appearance you see the Editior TAb at the Bottom of The TAB Appearence. Click on the tab After Clicking on that tab. After clicking on that tab you see your style sheet from their you can edit or update your style sheet.by the helpof this you easily eidt your stylesheet. But in this you need to find your css as where you properly need to edit.